# Loading specific rules file based on some condition

Tags: drools

I am new to Drools, so I apologize in advance if my question is very basic. Usually, if I have to load the rules file, I do something like this:

```
    KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
    KieContainer kContainer = kieServices.getKieClasspathContainer();
    kSession = kContainer.newStatelessKieSession();`
```

But how can I change the rules file based on some condition? Say I have 3 classes (A, B, and C) which implement an interface (P), and I also have a function which takes an object of type P (myFunction(P p){...}).

Now, based on the type of the object passed to myFunction(), I need to load different .drl file. For instance, a.drl if object is instance of A, and b.drl if instance of B. How can I do this in drools 6?

Comment: That's a strange question. When you write the call to myFunction, you know the type of the object passed as argument, and then you can modify the code loading the .drl file. Or even at runtime: in the method you can determine the class of `p`, and then decide which .drl file to load.

Comment: I would have to question whether you **really** need to load different knowledge bases depending on the object type. Rule matches are all based on the type of object anyway, so it would be more normal to have a single knowledge base with all the rules.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach I can think of would be to create multiple knowledge bases:

```
<kbase name="Kbase1" packages="rules.objectone">
    <ksession name="Kbase1Session" />
</kbase>
<kbase name="Kbase2" packages="rules.objecttwo">
    <ksession name="Kbase2Session" />
</kbase>
```

Then you can just write methods such as:

```
KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieContainer kContainer = kieServices.getKieClasspathContainer();

public void process(Object1 obj) {
    kSession = kContainer.newStatelessKieSession("Kbase1Session");
    kSession.insert(obj);
    kSession.fireAllRules();
}
public void process(Object2 obj) {
    kSession = kContainer.newStatelessKieSession("Kbase2Session");
    kSession.insert(obj);
    kSession.fireAllRules();
}
```

i.e. Use a different session for each object type.

Comment: Thanks, but would I have to create a separate package for every rules file? Right now, I have a package called "drools.rules" within which I have 2 .drl files (a.drl, and b.drl). If condition is "a", then I should use "a.drl", and if condition is "b", then I have to load "b.drl".

Comment: Yes you would ... although I'm still not convinced that you need to load different DRL depending on objects types.

Comment: @Steve Interesting suggestion. Do you think I can use this approach for my need? I am trying to build a rules KB for QC'ing test cases for consistency during development. I also want to create a production KB for when the tool is deployed. I guess I can pass a parameter token (DEV|PROD) and call the right process for the current task context. I'm also convinced there is going to be a need for different production rules. These approach seem to accommodate that. Your thoughts?

Comment: @hfontanez - From what you describe, it seems like a reasonable way to keep two knowledge bases that you could switch between based on an environment config.